# Removing a childViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I am adding a ChildViewController this way, which opens half the way of screen.

```
   m_customStartupView = [[CustomStartUpViewController alloc]init];
        m_customStartupView.delegate = self;

        if(m_showStatus == SHOW_STATUS)
        {
             m_customStartupView.dialogToShow = LAST_SYNC_STATUS;
        }       


        [self addChildViewController:m_customStartupView];
        [[self view] addSubview:[m_customStartupView view]];
        [m_customStartupView didMoveToParentViewController:self];


        CGRect rect = m_customStartupView.view.frame;
        if(IPHONE_5)
        {
            rect.origin.y = 568;
        }

        else
        {
            rect.origin.y = 480;
        }

        m_customStartupView.view.frame = rect;

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ShowView" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        if(IPHONE_5)
        {       
            rect.origin.y = 520;
        }
        else
        {
            rect.origin.y = 420;
        }

        m_customStartupView.view.frame = rect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

On dismiss of ChildView I am calling this:

```
-(void)dismissStartupAlertView:(BOOL)buttonClicked
{   
    CGRect rect = m_customStartupView.view.frame;
    if(IPHONE_5)
    {
        rect.origin.y =  520
    }
    else
    {
        rect.origin.y = 420 
    }
    m_customStartupView.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ShowView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    if(IPHONE_5)
    {
        rect.origin.y = 568;
    }
    else
    {
        rect.origin.y = 480;
    }

    m_customStartupView.view.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    if([animationID isEqualToString:@"ShowView"])
    {
        [m_customStartupView willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [m_customStartupView.view removeFromSuperview];
        [m_customStartupView removeFromParentViewController];
    }
}
```

So I have two buttons, Button 1 and Button 2, when user taps button1 a childView is animated from bottom and it shows. now if user presses button 2, then the previous childView is dismissed and then the new childView is shown

**So the problem is that if I tap both buttons very fast, like playing a casio, then childViews overlap.**

1)How can we fix this problem.

2) Whether I am doing it correctly

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily disabling button 2 while the animation is taking place :

```
   [button2 setEnabled:NO]
```

Then reverse this when the animation has  finished :

```
  [button2 setEnabled:YES]
```